# orthogonal operator preserves Inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

Well, Does orthogonal linear map preserves the inner product?

I know $T$ is orthogonal iff $||T(x)||^2=||x||^2$, and I know that two vector may not be orthogonal if we change the inner product, I have not example right now though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$, we can use the [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)
\begin{equation}
\langle x, y \rangle = \frac14 \left( \| x + y \|^2 - \|x - y\|^2 \right).
\end{equation}

So assuming $T$ preserves norms,
\begin{align*}
\langle Tx, Ty \rangle &= \frac14 \left( \| Tx + Ty \|^2 - \| Tx - Ty \|^2 \right) \\
&= \frac14 \left( \| T(x + y) \|^2 - \| T(x - y) \|^2 \right) \\
&= \frac14 \left( \| x + y \|^2 - \| x - y \|^2 \right) \\
&= \langle x, y \rangle.
\end{align*}